# Remove everything before the colon character (regex) in ms word

Tags: microsoft-word, regex

I need a regex to remove everything before the : character. An example would be:

> UNIDENTIFIED MALE #1: Thank you. Roll camera. Do you have numbers moving out at the sound?
>
> UNIDENTIFIED MALE #2:  No.
>
> UNIDENTIFIED MALE #1:  We need numbers moving on that.
>
> UNIDENTIFIED MALE #2:  No, it's not a smart...
>
> UNIDENTIFIED MALE #3:  Copy that. Stand by. Mark it.
>
> UNIDENTIFIED MALE #2:  Tatyana, take one. Mark.

becomes

> Thank you. Roll camera. Do you have numbers moving out at the sound?
>
> No.
>
> We need numbers moving on that.
>
> No, it's not a smart...
>
> Copy that. Stand by. Mark it.
>
> Tatyana, take one. Mark.

Something I want really bad

I tried variations of *: and <*: and <*:> and ^.+[:] to no avail. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: [Find and replace text by using regular expressions (Advanced)](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced--eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f?ui=en-US&rs=en-CA&ad=CA)

Answer (score 0):

Word's RegEX is pretty weird. :)  Try these settings:

- Find: `*: (*^13)`
- Replace: `\1`

This will match each line (`^13` = Carriage Return marker), and replace it with the part matched/found within the brackets (everything after the `:<space>`).

Here's a list of Word's RegEx's special characters:

```
   Characters    String Matches
   ------------------------------------------------------------------

       ^1         Picture (Except pictures with Float Over Text
                  property)
       ^2         Auto-referenced footnotes
       ^5         Annotation mark
       ^9         Tab
       ^11        New line
       ^12        Page OR section break
       ^13        Carriage return
       ^14        Column break
       ^19        Opening field brace
                      (when the field braces are visible)
       ^21        Closing field brace
                      (when the field braces are visible)
       ?          Question Mark
       ^?         Any single character
                      (not valid in the Replace box)
       ^-         Optional hyphen
       ^~         Non-breaking hyphen
       ^^         Caret character
       ^#         Any digit
       ^$         Any letter
       ^&         Contents of Find What box
                  (Replace box only)
       ^+         Em Dash (not valid in the Replace box)
       ^=         En Dash (not valid in the Replace box)
       ^u8195     Em Space Unicode character value search
                     (not valid in the Replace box)
       ^u8194     En Space Unicode character value search
                     (not valid in the Replace box)
       ^a         Comment
                     (not valid in the Replace box)
       ^b         Section Break (not valid in the Replace box)
       ^c         Replace with Clipboard contents (Replace box only)
       ^d         Field
       ^e         Endnote Mark (not valid in the Replace box)
       ^f         Footnote Mark (not valid in the Replace box)
       ^g         Graphic (Does not find graphics with the Float
                     Over Text property)
       ^l         New line
       ^m         Manual Page Break             
       ^n         Column break
       ^t         Tab
       ^p         Paragraph mark
       ^s         Non-breaking space
       ^w         White space (space, non-breaking space, tab; not valid
                  in the Replace box)
       ^nnn       Where "n" is an ASCII character number
       ^0nnn      Same as above, but uses ANSI characters (ALT+nnn PC only)
                  (Produces ASCII on Macintosh)
       ^unnnn     Word 97 Unicode character search where "n" is a decimal
                  number corresponding to the Unicode character value.
```

[Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/197855)

Comment: Hmm. [Find and replace text by using regular expressions (Advanced)](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced--eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f?ui=en-US&rs=en-CA&ad=CA) says "Any single character - `?` - `s?t` finds `sat` and `set.`" which is different from your source :/ Did this stuff all change between Word 97 and Word 2010?

Comment: @DavidPostill That is kind of strange, it may have...

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion but it's not finding the words up to and including :. See screenshot [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/1lw9slp5ccm91i8/Screenshot%202015-07-27%2011.14.01.png?dl=0)         If we can find a way to first find it, the replace will probably be the easier part. I'm using ms word 2007.

Comment: Judging by your screenshot it looks like you may not have turned on the "Use Wildcards" option in the Find/Replace dialog (under the `More >>` button)?